# File extension from byte[]

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, arrays

i have one data column in db it's contains **varbinary(max)**

Some of records will be stored in that table

now i want to find out file name and file extention (Mime type) from byte[]

it will be grate help if pass a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not generally possible. If the varbinary-column contains only the file contents there is no way to get the extension. If i would have designed the database there would be another column describing the filetype/extension.
If you know there are only images (as an example) in that column stored you could try to find out by looking for "specific bytes" of jpg, png, etc. files.